# Using Rectangle to Check Intersection of Images

Tags: java, user-interface, rectangles

So, I am instructed to: "Modify the Sprite class by implementing the "overlaps" function to return true if any portion of the Sprite passed in as an argument overlaps the current Sprite. You will need to use the x and y coordinates as well as the size of the Sprites."

I was advised to use Rectangles to make this work and check for an intersection. However, I'm not sure if what I have is the correct way to do this: (It's implemented in the boolean overlaps method)

As always, thanks so much for your time.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

abstract class Sprite
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int size;
    private int w;
    private int h;
    private int xSlope;
    private int ySlope;
    private Image image;
    private static Random rand;

    public Sprite(int xIn, int yIn, int width, int height, String imagePath, int imageSize) {
        if (rand == null) {
            rand = new Random();
        }
        size = imageSize;
        setImage(imagePath);
        x = xIn;
        y = yIn;
        w = width;
        h = height;
        xSlope = rand.nextInt(11) - 5;
        ySlope = rand.nextInt(11) - 5;
    }

    public int getX() { return x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }
    public int getSize() { return size; }
    public void setSize(int s) { size = s; }
    public void setX(int xIn) { x = xIn; }
    public void setY(int yIn) { y = yIn; }

    public void setImage(String imagePath) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Unable to load image file.");
        }
    }
    public Image getImage() { return image; }

    public boolean overlaps(Sprite s) {
        int locX = this.getX();
        int locY = this.getY();
        int overX = s.getX();
        int overY = s.getY();


        Rectangle R1 = new Rectangle(locX, locY, this.w, this.h);
        Rectangle R2 = new Rectangle(overX, overY, s.w, s.h );
        boolean intersects = R1.intersects(R2);
        return intersects;
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(getImage(), x, y, getSize(), getSize(), null);
    }

    public void move() {
        // Move the Sprite
        int x = getX() + xSlope;
        int y = getY() + ySlope;
        if (x < 0) x = w;
        if (x > w) x = 0;
        if (y < 0) y = h;
        if (y > h) y = 0;
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does what you have work and you're looking to see if it can be improved?

Comment: Why don't you write some junit tests to see if you're getting the desired behaviour?

Comment: Did you try to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749851/faster-way-to-check-intersected-rectangles), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825515/java-rectangle-collision-detection-confusion), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231685/collision-detection-while-using-rectangles) and another 20 links?